# Angular POST request with multipart file and other params

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, post

I'd like to make a POST request from angular whereas the backend developer's waiting for a spring boot request like this, with 3 params :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> importFile(
            @RequestParam(value = "type") Dto dto,
            @RequestParam(value = "booleanValue", required = false) Boolean booleanValue,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {
```

In Angular side I'm trying to build a form data, but I'm unable to add the boolean when I write this :

```
importFile(fileToImport: FileToImport, booleanValue?: boolean) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('type', fileToImport.type);
    formData.append('booleanValue', booleanValue);
    formData.append('file', fileToImport.file);
    return this.http.post('/import', formData);
  }
```

force has got an error : `Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'`

So how can I put 3 arguments to respect the backend ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the `FileToImport` type?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It's my boolean I'm unable to add to my formData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a boolean value into the `formData.append` function. You should instead convert it to a string.

```js
importFile(fileToImport: FileToImport, booleanValue?: boolean) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('type', fileToImport.type);
  formData.append('force', booleanValue.toString());
  formData.append('file', fileToImport.file);
  return this.http.post('/import', formData);
}
```

If your backend is particular about how boolean values are parsed, you may need a bit more treatment. Bear in mind that Javascript string representation of boolean values are `"true"` and `"false"`.